# How solve this error using session on play framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

i started a little project with play framework 2 . anyway i got this error using session:
(image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAnmz.png

classes are here:
https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan/blob/master/app/services/Authenticator.java

Can you tell me where is the problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it's because session() is a static call that is part of the Controller in the API as seen at this link http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0.4/java/index.html.

To fix this, you could either reference it statically or have your service extend Controller (which I can't imagine you would want)

```
public static boolean isCurrentUserLogged() {
    return play.mvc.Controller.session("id_user") != null;
}
```